# Bootstrapping data envelopment analysis efficiency score using R

Tags: r, bootstrap, efficiency

I want to perform bootstrapping for calculation of efficiency score from data envelopment analysis (DEA) using R.

- Are there any examples of data and results for this type of analysis in R to enable me to check my results?
- Are there any online or other resources that might assist my task?

Comment: @user4472, please provide some context and more details, otherwise the question will be closed. Also see faq on how to ask questions.

Comment: @mpiktas I asked @user4472 to post their question on this site after I received an email from them. @user4472 I've endeavoured to convert your question into something more reasonable, feel free to edit, if I have misconstrued.

Comment: @Jeromy Anglim, thanks for explanation, I've upvoted the question.

Answer (score 5):

Although this question was asked long time ago I am going to give an answer for following googlers.

The book

> Peter Bogetoft and Lars Otto, (2011). [Benchmarking with DEA, SFA, and R](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Benchmarking-International-Operations-Research-Management/dp/1441979603), Springer.

provides detailed answers to your question. Read Chapter 6 "Statistical Analysis in DEA".

They implemented the described method in the CRAN Package [Benchmarking](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Benchmarking/Benchmarking.pdf) in the `dea.boot()` function.

I hope it helps!
Daniel